# How were Chanda and Munda born?

Tags: devi, asuras, kali, birth

Chanda and Munda were asuras who were killed by Kali. This is alluded to in many hymns and prayers to Devi, such as in the Mahishasura Mardini Stotram and the Lalita Sahasranamam.

But there is little information about how these two asuras were born. Were they brothers? Who was their mother? Is there some sort of explanation of this somewhere in the scriptures?